# Difficulty in calculating equation with unknowns

Tags: calculus

can you help me solve this one?

$2x+y=32 \\2p+q=17\\y+6q=?$

I got $0=0$ so I guess I failed somewhere on the way.

Comment: What are $x,y,p$, and $q$ ?

Comment: You have 4 variables but only 2 definitions.

Comment: No idea, it’s all I have got

Comment: So it is unsolvable, right? Cause I feel bad for not suceeding

Comment: Well you can express it in terms of $x$ and $p$, but you can't determine specific numbers.

Comment: $y = 32 - 2x, q = 17 - 2p, y+6q = (32-2x) + 6(17-2p)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the first equation:
$$y=32-2x$$
from the second equation:
$$
q=17-2p
$$

so you can find 
$$
y+6q=32-2x+6(17-2p)
$$